# Creating prototype chains in JavaScript (ES-5)

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to create a function that creates an object with a prototype chain, like this:

```
something = object(proto1, proto2, proto3);
// Lookup order is something -> proto1 -> proto2 -> proto3 -> Object.prototype
```

I'd to wrap the given prototypes to override their own lookup chains (so they can be reused), and want to do so with minimal copying/inner attribute wrapping.

Is there any feature in Javascript/ECMAScript 5 that can be used to override **all** attribute accesses on an object? Something akin to `__getattribute__(self, attrname)` in Python? If not, how should I go about this? Am I forced to just clone the object's properties (with `Object.hasOwnProperty()`)?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has prototypes, so could use a construct like:

```
// Small utility function
function Object.extend(obj, properties) {
    for (var i in properties) {
        obj[i] = properties[i];
    }
    return obj;
}

// Create a subclass of Object 
function Class3() {}
Class3.prototype = proto3;

// Create a subclass of Class3
function Class2() {}
Class2.prototype = new Class3();
Object.extend(Class2.prototype, proto2);

// Create a subclass of Class2
function Class1() {}
Class1.prototype = new Class2();
Object.extend(Class1.prototype, proto1);

// Instantiate an object whose prototype chain is proto1, proto2, proto3
var something = new Class1();
```

Comment: I appreciate your time, but this doesn't answer my question in any way =/

Comment: Sorry. I must have misunderstood your question.